# If $f(z)$ is analytic how about $\overline{f(z)}$ and $f(\bar{z})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Are they generally not or are they always not?  How can it be proven that they're not?

Comment: Well...$f(z)=f(\,\overline z\,)$ for $z\in \mathbb R$ so if the latter were also entire then it would have to coincide with $f(z)$, forcing $f$ to be a constant.  If $\overline {f(z)}$ were entire then the product $f(z)\overline {f(z)}$ would be entire, but the latter is always real...again forcing $f$ to be a constant.

Comment: What if $f$ is constant? If $f(z) = z$ for all $z$...?

Answer (score 6):

If $f(z)$ and $\overline{f(z)}$ are analytic, then so is $h(z):=f(z)+\overline{f(z)}$, but the latter is real-valued (since $w+\overline{w}=2\textrm{Re}(w)$ ). Thus, the imaginary part of $h$ is zero,  and this, by the Cauchy Riemann equations implies that the real part of $h$ is constant, so $h$ is a real constant (on each connected component of its domain).

Arguing similarly, one sees that $f(z)-\overline{f(z)}$ is an imaginary constant.

Combining the above (add the two functions that we constructed), we obtain that $f(z)$ is a constant.

In order to deal with $f(\overline z)$, note that $g(z)= \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is analytic, and apply the previous case.